# Why is my preview crashing when I try to press a button to go to another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Using iOS 16.0 and Xcode 14.2

I am super new to SwiftUI and it honestly still hasn't really clicked yet, so this code probably is very inefficient.  But basically I just want a button that when you press it, you go to another view.  But when I try it like this, the preview crashes.  Is there a better way to do this?  And also what is causing the preview to crash?  I've tried a bunch of different things and it either causes the preview to crash or the button just doesn't do anything.

Homescreen (had other buttons that were working that I redacted for clarity)

```
import SwiftUI

struct WordAndArrows: View {

@State private var showLibrary = false

    var body: some View {
       
            LibraryButton (action: {
                self.navigateToLibraryScreen()
            })            
        }
        
        VStack {
            if showLibrary {
                LibraryView()
            }
        }
    }
    func navigateToLibraryScreen() {
        self.showLibrary = true
    }

}


struct WordAndArrows_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ZStack {
GradientBackground()
WordAndArrows()
    }
  }
}
```

Library Button View

```
import SwiftUI

struct LibraryButton: View {
    var action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        //Button("Check out my library") {
        Button(action: action) {
                    Text("Library")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color("Lime"))
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .buttonStyle(SquishButtonStyle(fadeOnPress: false))
                .font(Font.custom("Quicksand-Bold", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(Color("Indigo"))
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2.5, x: 0, y: 5)
            }
        }
```

I tried:

1. Making a navigatetolibraryscreen function that would be triggered when the buttn was hit
2. Using a navigationLink
   3  Wrapping the navigation link in a Vstack

And it either caused the button to not do anything or the preview to crash

Comment: It is difficult to debug because we know nothing about the crash. Probably the best way to debug this is to reproduce it in an app where you can use the debugger. Another thing you can do is open Console.app, click “Crash Reports” in the sidebar, then click the “Date” column header (probably twice) to sort the newest report to the top. Then you can look at the crash report from the preview and maybe get some useful info.